# PHP - Check if a file exists in a folder

Tags: php

I wanna check if there any image on a folder from my server. I have this little function in PHP but is not working and I don't know why:

```
$path = 'folder/'.$id;
function check($path) {
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        $array = array();
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && count > 2) {
                echo "folder not empty";
            } else {
                echo "folder empty";
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the `count` variable (I'm assuming)? Does it ever change?

Answer (score 5):

It does not work because `count` is coming from nowhere. Try this instead:

```
$path = 'folder/'.$id;
function check($path) {
    $files = glob($path.'/*');
    echo empty($files) ? "$path is empty" : "$path is not empty";
}
```

Comment: Vars out of quotes... Can debug much of your code ;) http://www.pfz.nl/wiki/variabelen-buiten-quotes/ (dutch)

Comment: Just try to translate it with google translate... It is a article that explains the (bad) behavior of php with: `"$path is empty"`

Comment: I wasn't asking about the article, I got that part. It's just your comment that doesn't make sense. Besides, there's nothing wrong with PHP's variable expansion and parsing... Perl does it, Bash does it, a lot of other do it as well. It's only wrong when you use it wrong.

Comment: I didn't say something is wrong... (I'm thinking to much in my native language.) My comment is on the `"$path is empty"` and `"$path is not empty"` part of your answer... If you build a whole system, using double quotes `"` and variables inside these quotes `"$path"` then your system will slow down when you have much refreshes... Use `'` instead of `"` and `$path.' is empty'`. This can give your system a boost if it is big enough...

Answer (score 1):

Try this function: http://www.php.net/glob

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$path = 'folder/'.$id;
function check($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        $contents = scandir($path);
        if(count($contents) > 2) {
            echo "folder not empty";
        } else {
            echo "folder empty";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

It counts the contents of the path. If there are more than two items, then its not empty. The two items we are ignoring are "." and "..".

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1: $query = select * from your_table where id=$id;
Step 2: $path=$query['path_column'];
Step 3: if($path!=null&&file_exit($path)&&$dir=opendir($path)){
           while (($file = readdir($dir )) !== false)
            {
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if($file) // file get 
                { 
                    $allowedExts = array("jpg");
                    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
                    $file[]=$file;
                }
                $data[file_name'] = $file;
            }
             closedir($dir);
        }
```